# Users keeps getting Access denied until Enabling/disabling anonymous access

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, anonymous-authentication, access-denied

We have 3 web applications in our SharePoint 2013-intranet solution. Two of them works fine. On the third one **"sometimes"** users get **Access denied.** This includes farm admin users as well.

After following [this](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8565/sharepoint-2013-access-denied-to-root-site-of-web-application) tip, the problem is solved (enabling Anonymous auth, waiting, verifying and set it back). But a few hours/days the problem occurs again and its keeps happening.

Anyone have got this or have a clue were to look/compare with the other, working web  applications?

Comment: what authentication being used? also how manys ite collections in that web app? what template is being used for root site collection?

Comment: Hej Waqas! Thanks for a Quick response :) we are using Claims Based Auth(on all) and ordinary http (not https). Right now there are only one site coll on the webapp. The root site is using BLANKINTERNET on the non-working, BLANKINTERNET on one of the working (root)sites and STS on the other working

Comment: did ou configure the Object Cache(Super User and Super Reader) on that web app?

Comment: No, for none of the web apps

Comment: try to configure that and then test it....make sure when you run the powershell dont froget the adding claims with your super user and reader account claim:domain\spreader...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx

Comment: didnt help. Still an unsolved mystery

Comment: Waqas: It turns out, you were right. Please add last comment as answer so  I cant set it to "correct answer"... and I guess you get some credits :)

Comment: I am glad it fix your problem, I added that as anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much common error now days which occur when you ignore the Object Cache Settings. So Please Configure the Object Cache settings for that web App.

- Create the **Super User** and **Super Reader** Account
- Add Both account into Policy for web app, **Super Reader as Full read** and **Super User as Full control**
- Now run the below power shell to add the user:

  $wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity ""

  $wa.Properties["portalsuperuseraccount"] = ""

  $wa.Properties["portalsuperreaderaccount"] = ""

  $wa.Update()
- IIS reset on all server in the farm.

**Note:** when you add the user in the powershell,Dont Forget the Claims in start of account i.e.`claim:domain\spreader`.

[Configure object cache user accounts in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx)